# Differential equation solution mistake in a textbook?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$m*x''=-kx'$ where $x'=dx/dt$
Hello everyone.Can someone please explain to me how the solution for this equation in the textbook is $$x(t)=Ce^{-kt/m}$$, and i get $$x=\frac {k}m C_1e^{-kt/m}+C_2$$
What am i doing wrong.Thanks

Comment: Are there any initial conditions present?

Comment: Note that the values of $k$ and $m$ can be absorbed into your $C_1$ so aren't needed but aren't wrong either.

Comment: Oh i see Ian, that was the problem for me, how did he loose k and m, and that exactly bothered me, so k and m can be absobed in C, i didnt know that, thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is
$ x= C_1e^{-kt/m}+C_2.$
But I think the textbook have forgotten to write 
$C_{2}$.

Comment: Could you please explain the steps if it's not a problem.

Comment: $m* r^{2}=-k*r\;\Rightarrow\; r=-k/m\, ,\, r=0$

Comment: I undertsand Hamed, but how did he loose k/m? Can that factor be absorbed into C1? Since this is a problem in classical mechanics, k and m have units and C does not?

Comment: $\frac{k}{m}C_1$ is a constant. Hence we say it another constant. Isn't $C$ nice?